# How can I get the characters that come after the @ on email value with python?

Tags: python, email, get, at-command

I want to know what comes especificaly after the "@" on an email value that is in an input with python, what are ways to do it?

Examples:
email: input("Write your email: ")

User input:
Write you email: XXXX@hotmail.com

JohnDoe@hotmail.com
result: hotmail.com

Nick@gmail.com
result: gmail.com

I have no idea on how I can do it, but I would try manging strings and using len()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
email = 'XXXX@hotmail.com'

#Get the index of '@' with find method and add 1 to it
idx = email.find('@') + 1

#Get the character with email[idx]
required_character = email[idx]

print(required_character) #output : 'h'

#to get the domain name after the symbol @
domain = email[idx:]
print(domain) #output : hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `input("Write your email: ").split("@")[1]` to split the string into a list of the two parts separated by `@` and take the second part with `[1]` (the hotmail.com or gmail.com).

Answer (score 0):

email = input("Write your email: ")

at_index = email.find("@")

if at_index != -1:

domain = email[at_index + 1:]
print(f"Domain: {domain}")
else:
print("Invalid email format")

Answer (score 0):

It's handled by the following in Django validators:

```
 username_part, domain_part = value.rsplit("@", 1)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rsplit.asp

```
In [1]: 'abc@xyz.com'.rsplit('@', 1)
Out[1]: ['abc', 'xyz.com']
```